# How can I create an instance using a member in ArrayList<Class>

Tags: java

I created an ArrayList to store Classes. Then I would like to use the members in the ArrayList to create an instance. How can I instantiate?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Machine{
    public String toString(){
        return "I am a machine";
    }
}

class MyMachine extends Machine{
    public String toString(){
        return "This is a super Machine";
    }
}


class MyClass<T> {
    public static <T> void showString(T abc){
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}

public class myfun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Class> hahalist = new ArrayList<>();

        hahalist.add(MyClass.class);
        hahalist.add(Machine.class);
        hahalist.add(MyClass.class);

        // Machine abc = new Machine();
        // I can't do this
        // abc = hahalist.get(1);

        // I can't do this either
        // hahalist.get(1) abc = new hahalist.get(1)()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a no args constructor on all you classes you can just use the Class.newInstance(), eg

```
try {
    Object x = hahaList.get(0).newInstance(); 
} catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
}
```

(I haven't got my IDE open so haven't verified the exact syntax).

If you've got arguments to the constructor then its a bit more convoluted. You can read the full details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: Just tried but doesn't work as : Error:(38, 47) java: unreported exception java.lang.InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Comment: newInstance throws a checked exceptions so you need to handle these in you code, eg put try catch statement around your newInstance call. According to the javadoc it can throw InstantiationException and IllegalAccessException so you'll need to make sure you handle both of these.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing classes in the list, you could store references to the constructors:

```
List<Supplier<Object>> hahalist = new ArrayList<>();

hahalist.add(MyClass::new);
hahalist.add(Machine::new);
hahalist.add(MyMachine::new);

Object instance = hahalist.get(1).get(); // Calling constructor
```

Because `MyClass` and `Machine` have a closest common ancestor of `Object` that is the return type of the `Supplier` I'm using here.